# Cannot change variable in useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to change the values of variables within a useEffect call in js React.
I notice that the values get changed inside of the function, but the global value is not changed.

```
var O_name = "";
var A_name = "";
var A_platform = "";
var C_name = "";

function Statsview( {backButton} ) {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const name = urlParams.get('name');
    
    var data = useRef();
    const [overwatchName, setO_Name] = useState([]); 

    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounted')
        database.collection('USERS').where('name','==',name).get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                var data = doc.data()
                O_name = data.overwatch;
                console.log(O_name)
                A_name = data.apexLegends;
                console.log(A_name)
                A_platform = data.apexLegendsPlatform;
                console.log(A_platform)
                C_name = data.chess;
                console.log(C_name)
            })
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))      
    },[]);

    console.log("oname: ",O_name)
    console.log("aname: ",A_name)
    console.log("aplat: ",A_platform)
    console.log("cname: ",C_name)
...
...
}
```

The console logs inside of the useEffect show updated values for each varaible.
However, the console logs outside of the useEffect show that the values for each variable are blank.

How do I change these global values?

Comment: a) don't use global variables b) the global variables *do* change. Your `console.log` just happens *before* they change - both `useEffect` and `.then()` are asynchronous

Comment: Why don't you simply use `setO_Name(data.overwatch);` instead of `O_name = data.overwatch;`?

Comment: You cant, define global vars inside the `useEffect`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables and functions are initiated when React first load all the scripts, that means when you first load (or reload) the page. React itself is not aware of the mutation of these global variables.

Your code flow is like this.

1. Global variables are initialized.
2. `console.log()` prints the content when a component is loaded.
3. An async call mutates the global variables => React is not aware of them. hence does not re-render your component. Hence, `console.log()` is not called.

You should use state hook to store these variables so React knows they are changed.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `useRef` for this case.

so for simple example.

```
function MyComponent(){
   const A_name = useRef('');
   
   useEffect(() => {
      A_name.current = 'new value'
   }, []);
}
```

You can change/access the variable with `.current` property

You can read more at docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

It mentioned: *useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.*

So it would fit your objective